# AHK CSV Parse can't Parse line by line

Tags: csv, autohotkey

Using Autohotkey, I Looking at [AHK Document](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopParse.htm).

My File that i want to read type is CSV, so i testing Example 4

[image]

This is my CSV file. 2 Row, some column.

So, If open file, data will read comma by comma, and **line by line**. right?

But..

[image]

[image]

[image]

It is Printed answer.

What the freaking this situation?

Why AHK CSV Parse is not cutting data line by line?

Need Some help : <

P.S : Code is same as Example 4.

```
Loop, Parse, PositionData, CSV
{
MsgBox, 4, , Field %LineNumber%-%A_Index% is:`n%A_LoopField%`n`nContinue?
IfMsgBox, No, break 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found.

If CSV Reading in AHK, You must read Line by Line...